# c++ - how to properly overload operator to do implicit type cast from __generic_buffer<void*> to __generic_buffer<const void*>?

Tags: c++, types, casting, type-conversion

To put it simple, i have the following code:

```
template<typename p>
requires(std::is_pointer<p>::value)
struct __generic_buffer 
{
    p baseptr;
    size_t size;

    // member functions go here
};

using buffer = __generic_buffer<void*>;
using const_buffer = __generic_buffer<const void*>;
```

and i want to be able to write something like that:

```
uint8_t arr[64];
buffer b {arr, 64};
const_buffer cb = b;
```

so basically i want `buffer` pointing to modifiable memory area to be freely castable to `const_buffer` pointing to constant memory area, but not the other way around, just how usual pointers behave. Also, i'd prefer this conversion to work with any other instantiation of `__generic_buffer`, e.g. `__generic_buffer<int*>` to `__generic_buffer<const int*>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first.  Types with `__` in them are reserved by the C++ standard for your compiler and the standard library.  Use of them in programs makes your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required.  (also, `_T` starting with an `_` and then a capital letter).

This kind of bad habit comes from copying the coding style of `std` headers and the like.  They are allowed to do that, and in fact **must** do that, because if they called something `bob`, someone could legally `#define bob alice` and break the header file.

---

There are two ways to do what you want.

One of them involves writing a converting constructor, the other a converting operator.

I'll show the operator way.

```
template<class P>
requires(std::is_pointer<P>::value)
struct generic_buffer 
{
  P baseptr;
  size_t size;

  template<class U>
  requires(std::is_same<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_pointer_t<U>>, std::remove_pointer_t<P>>::value)
  operator generic_buffer<U>() const {
    return {baseptr, size};
  }
  // member functions go here
};
```

I might write a trait rather than do that `requires` inline, but basically we check if `*U` is the same type as `*P` after removing `const` and `volatile` from `*U`.

If so, we allow this conversion operator to exist.

Inside, we use implicit conversion to convert the pointer types.

Now, this isn't **perfect**, because we really want to check if removing either of const, volatile or both would make it match.  You might want to write a type function that does that test.

The constructor way is just the above, but backwards.  Declaring a constructor has some impact on the automatic constructors and the triviality of a type, while an operator like this doesn't, so to avoid having to digress into those issues I implemented it as an operator.

Comment: Might we instead lean on `std::assignable_from`?

Comment: @AndyG, not in this scenario. If we try to use ```std::assignable_from``` in this context, then we'll be able to cast generic_buffer<int*> with size of, lets say, 30, to generic_buffer<void*>. generic_buffer<void*>::size is treated like size in bytes, while generic_buffer<int*>::size is, essentially, count of integers.